# Keyboard with detachable cable and usb hub

Tags: keyboards

I am looking for a keyboard for programming (not gaming).

Requirements:

- **Detachable USB cable** (the same as smartphones use - USB A to Micro USB-B)
- **Weight**: Has to be heavy. At least 800g. Heavier is better.
- **Rubber pads**
- **Format**: DE: QWERTZ

  - Enter at the very right (or at least enough space between enter and anything more right so that I don't hit e.g. page up/down when I want to hit enter)
- **USB Hub**: I would like to be able to plug in a USB stick / a mouse
- **Backlight**: Should be possible to switch it on and off
- **Not ergonomic**: I can't type on those.
- **Not too flat**: I use the Thinkpad T460p and I like how the keyboard feels. I've tried some Mac Notebooks and they feel much too flat for me.

Nice to have:

- **Mouse**: A small touchpad / trackpoint / trackball - if it is big, I don't want it.
- **Bluetooth-Capability** (especially if I have a hardware-switch to turn it on / off)

Not necessary:

- **Num block** (I slightly prefer not to have it)
- **Media keys**: I'm not sure about this, but I don't see an advantage in comparison to creating custom commands (I'm a Ubuntu user)

### Considered so far

#### CODE keyboard ([88 Key](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/index.php/products/code-keyboard/code-88-key-ger-mechanical-keyboard.html))

- Detachable USB cable ✔
- 907g ✔
- Rubber pads ✔
- QWERTZ format available ✔
- USB Hub ✘
- Backlight ✔
- Not ergonomic ✔
- Not too flat ✔
- Mouse ✘
- Nice design - judging from photos only, I guess the keys feel nice.